# Stock not available at home country nor at their local market - where should I buy it

Tags: foreign-exchange, stock-markets, stock-exchanges, foreign-currency

I would like to buy a stock of a company, unfortunately I don't have access to the stock in my local stock exchange nor do I have access to the stock exchange of the country of the company.

But I would have access to two other markets which have the stocks.

It would look like this:

[image]

(Yes, I just realized that I'm bad at drawing stuff)

From the picture you can see that I can't "access" the stock directly.
Now the question is:

**Which Stock Exchange should I prefer?**

Both cost me the same from fees, both are same level of complexity regarding taxes. In addition, the currencies are not bound with each other (no fixed exchange rate)

Comment: Maybe someone who's more fluent in English can rephrase the title for me... the stock IS available in the country of the company, I just don't have access to that stock market.

Comment: What's ATS? SGD presumably is Singapore Dollar, but the only ATS I can see was the Austrian Schilling which no longer exists (replaced with EUR). Other things being equal, I guess you want the exchange where conversion from your currency (?) to the exchange's currency (USD/EUR) to the stock's currenct (SGD) is less likely to fluctuate.

Comment: In efficient markets it wouldn't matter, there cannot be a difference between the prices.  So the only question is how to hedge SGD and/or EUR or USD risk, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theoretically, it shouldn't matter which one you use.  Your return should only depend on the stock returns in SGD and the ATS/SGD exchange rate (Austrian Schillings? is this an question from a textbook?).  Whether you do the purchase "through" EUR or USD shouldn't matter as the fluctuations in either currency "cancel" when you do the two part exchange SGD/XXX then XXX/ATS.

Now, in practice, the cost of exchanging currencies might be higher in one currency or the other.  Likely a tiny, tiny amount higher in EUR.  There is some risk as well as you will likely have to exchange the money and then wait a day or two to buy the stock, but the risk should be broadly similar between USD and EUR.

Comment: I used ATS to obscure the stock I'm interessted and to make it more obvious the currencies don't have any connection. Anywway an excellent answer, thanks a lot

Comment: ahh... fair.  Good luck with the trade.